# SQL json_extract returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-athena, mysql-json

I am attempting to extract from my json object

```
hits = [{“title”: “Facebook”,
         “domain”: “facebook.com”},
        {“title”: “Linkedin”,
         “domain”: “linkedin.com”}]
```

When I use:
`json_extract(hits,'$.title') as title,`
nothing is returned. I would like the result to be: [Facebook, Linkedin].
However, when I extract by a scalar value, ex.:
`json_extract_scalar(hits,'$[0].title') as title,`
it works and Facebook is returned.
hits contains a lot of values, so I need to use json_extract in order to get all of them, so I can't do each scalar individually. Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

I get INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON path: '$**.title' as an error for $**.title (double stars). When I try unnest I get INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: varchar as an error and INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: json. I get SYNTAX_ERROR: line 26:19: Column '$.title' cannot be resolved when I try double quotes

Comment: Do you need mysql or athena query?

Answer (score 0):

Fits you have an array. So $.title doesn't exist see below

Second, you have not a valid json, is must have double quotes " like the example shows

```
 SET @a := '[{
        "title": "Facebook",
        "domain": "facebook.com"
    },
    {
 
        "title": "Linkedin",
        "domain": "linkedin.com"
    }
 ]'

 SELECT json_extract(@a,'$[0]') as title
```

```
 | title                                           |
 | :---------------------------------------------- |
 | {"title": "Facebook", "domain": "facebook.com"} |
```

```
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@a, "$[0].title") AS 'from'
```

```
 | from       |
 | :--------- |
 | "Facebook" |
```

```
 SELECT @a
```

```
 | @a                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
 | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
 | [{<br>                "title": "Facebook",<br>                "domain": "facebook.com"<br>        },<br>        {<br><br>                "title": "Linkedin",<br>                "domain": "linkedin.com"<br>        }<br>] |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2c45438c788a251158e62848e97f2a90)*

Comment: Thanks. But how do I extract all titles? Not just the first one.

Comment: Use Instead of 0 * JSON has to be learnt so read up on it or use a normalized table

Answer (score 0):

Correct json path to exract all titles is `$.[*].title` (or `$.*.title`), though it is not supported by athena. One option is to cast your json to array of json and use transform on it:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       
       (JSON '[{"title": "Facebook",
         "domain": "facebook.com"},
        {"title": "Linkedin",
         "domain": "linkedin.com"}]')
 ) AS t (json_string))


SELECT transform(cast(json_string as ARRAY(JSON)), js -> json_extract_scalar(js, '$.title'))
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [Facebook, Linkedin] |